# How do I add a new album, or change existing albums, in Photos on my phone?

Tags: 8.0, photos

I can't seem to find an option to add a new album, or edit the existing "Camera Roll" album (other than to delete it), on my phone. Is this something only available when working with the data on OneDrive or on my computer? If this function is not natively supported on the phone, is there an app or add-on I can install to add it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't create new albums from within the pictures hub, but you can install the [OneDrive app](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/onedrive/9wzdncrfj1p3) and manage folders on OneDrive with that.

Answer (score 3):

Each album in the hub corresponds to

- a folder in the Pictures folder (when you connect it to a computer)
- a "Pictures" folder on OneDrive (mark as Pictures in a folder's properties)
- a Facebook album

You can delete any folder which isn't the Camera roll, a OneDrive folder or Facebook album by long pressing on it and tapping delete.

The camera roll must be called camera roll. The camera and lens apps will save pictures here. Any other app may only save pictures to the "saved pictures" folder (so an app cannot create a new folder).

You can't rename folders on the phone.